# Is it possible to have a unique theme for Vim in Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, server, themes, vim

I recently started managing my own Ubuntu Server and I'm constantly using Vim to edit my files and I was wondering if it was possible to install a them to use overtime I login to my server?

The reason for my question is because if I log into my server using the terminal it uses the them I'm using in my terminal and if I login using Putty it uses the them Putty is using.

I tried to install a theme for Vim and nothing changes but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it is just not possible.

Is it possible to have a special theme for Vim in Ubuntu Server?

Thanks

Comment: It's called `colorscheme` in Vim. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_color_schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue being new to Ubuntu server and the default colorscheme wasn't working for my eyes.

The colorschemes for vim are at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors`.

Doing a basic search for VIM ColorSchemes will show you examples of the schemes and ones you can download and place in the above directory.

Then I edited the `vimrc` file

```
sudo vi /etc/vim/vimrc
```

if memory serves me correctly I had to manually enter

```
colorscheme NameOfColorScheme
```

example:

```
colorscheme blackboard
```

Do note this edits the default vim colorscheme for all users.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Finally, you are right `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors` this is the right directory, I have been trying `~/.vim/colors` since everyone recommends that folder but wasn't working. The only thing I did different is that I listed my theme name in `~/.vimrc` and it works, I really don't know what the difference is between this file and the one you referenced but it woks on both. Thanks a lot.

Comment: /etc/vim/vimrc are the default settings for all users.
~/.vimrc is user specific preferences / settings